# Update trigger map issue

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

Edit: I've gotten stuck trying to get my test coverage above 64% on this trigger. When I update the test record, I get coverage for the Follow_Up_Date__c field change but not for applicationMap.put(application.Id, application); A few lines down - if (applicationMap.size() > 0){ gets coverage. But then nothing below that gets coverage.

I've checked the debug logs and the application Id exists but the Id doesn't get populated in the Map. Any ideas on why the Map won't populate?

Class:

```
public void updateLastActivityDate(){

    Map<Id, Application__c> applicationMap = new Map<Id, Application__c>();

    if (Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isUpdate)){
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Test 1');
        for (Application__c application : (List<Application__c>) Trigger.new){
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, application);
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Test 1.1');
            if (Utils.isFieldChanging('Follow_Up_Date__c', application, Trigger.oldMap)){
                System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Test 1.2');
                applicationMap.put(application.Id, application);
                System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, applicationMap);
            }
        }
    }



    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Task 1.3');    
    if (applicationMap.size() > 0){

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Task 1.4');
        List<Task> tasks = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, WhatId FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN :applicationMap.keySet() AND CreatedDate = TODAY];

        List<Application__c> applicationsToUpdate = new List<Application__c>();
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Task 1.5');
        if (tasks.isEmpty()){
            for (Application__c application : (List<Application__c>) Trigger.new){
                    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Test error message');
                    application.addError('An activity must be logged today to change the Follow-Up Date');
            }   
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Test 1.6');    
        if (tasks.size() > 0){
            for (Id applicationId : applicationMap.keySet()){
                Application__c app = applicationMap.get(applicationId);
                if (app != null){
                    Application__c a = new Application__c(
                    Id=applicationId,
                    Last_Activity_Date__c = System.TODAY()
                    );
                    applicationsToUpdate.add(a);
                    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, applicationsToUpdate);
                }
            }

            if (applicationsToUpdate.size() > 0){
                update applicationsToUpdate;
                System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, applicationsToUpdate);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Test class:

```
static testMethod void updateLastActivityDate(){
    //CaseShareDelete.doChainJob = false;
    TestFuel fuel = new TestFuel();
    Utils u = new Utils();

    User thisUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

    Profile p = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'WV Operations Users'];
    User u1 = fuel.newOperationsUser();
    insert u1;

        System.runAs(u1){   
            Account account = fuel.newAccount();
            Account carrier = fuel.newCarrierAccount();
            Account brokerDealer = fuel.newBrokerDealerAccount();
        insert new List<Account>{account, carrier, brokerDealer};

        Contract contract = fuel.newContract();
        contract.RecordTypeId = '01236000000SBRzAAO';
        contract.AccountId = account.Id;
        contract.Status = 'Draft';
        insert contract;

        Territory__c territory = fuel.newTerritory();
        insert territory;

        Contact contact = fuel.newContact();
        contact.RecordTypeId = '012360000008QLxAAM';
        contact.AccountId = account.Id;
        contact.Broker_Dealer__c = brokerDealer.Id;
        contact.Wealthvest_Producer_ID__c = contract.Id;
        contact.Contact_Stage__c = '6 - Contracted Producer';
        contact.Territory__c = territory.Id;
        insert contact;

        Appointment__c appointment = fuel.newCarrierAppointment();
        appointment.Producer_Contact__c = contact.Id;
            appointment.Carrier__c = carrier.Id;
            appointment.WV_Producer_Contract__c = contract.Id;
            //appointment.Status__c = null;
            appointment.Carrier_Appointment_Stage__c = '4-Pending with Carrier';
            insert appointment;

        CarrierLine__c carrierLine = fuel.newCarrierLine();
        carrierLine.Carrier__c = carrier.Id;
        insert carrierLine;

        CarrierLineProduct__c product = fuel.newProduct();
        product.Carrier__c = carrier.Id;
        product.CarrierLine__c = carrierLine.Id;
        insert product;

            Application__c application = fuel.newApplication(); 
            application.RecordTypeId = '01236000000SKvhAAG';
            application.Policy_Number__c = 'W92745100';
            application.Tax_Status__c = 'Qualified';
            application.Gender__c = 'Male';
            application.Age__c = 43;
            application.Application_Stage__c = '00 - WV Preliminary App Review';
            application.Status__c = 'Reviewed by WV, App Not Submitted to Carrier';
            application.Investor__c = 'Sam Test';
        application.Carrier__c = carrier.Id;    
            application.Product_Carrier__c = product.Id;
            application.Submitted_Premium__c = 100000;
            application.Sign_Date__c = System.today() - 7;
            application.Signed_State__c = 'CA';
            application.Application_Sent_To__c = 'WealthVest';
            application.Issue_Status_Only__c = 'Full Case Management';
            application.DOB__c = Date.newInstance(1975, 12, 9);
            application.Received_Date__c = System.today() - 2;
            application.Submitted__c = System.today();
            application.Submitted_Premium__c = 100000;
            application.Investor_SSN__c = '756342132';
            application.Carrier_Appointment__c = appointment.Id;
        insert application;

            Application_Line_Item__c ali = fuel.newApplicationLine();
            ali.Application__c = application.Id;
            insert ali;

            Producer_Application_Line_Item__c pali = fuel.newProducerApplicationLineItem();
        pali.Application_Line_Item__c = ali.Id;
        pali.Producer__c = contact.Id;
        pali.Split_pct__c = 100.00;
        insert pali;

        List<Application__c> applicationList = [SELECT Id FROM Application__c WHERE Id = :application.Id];
        System.assertEquals(1, applicationList.size());

        Test.startTest();

        List<Task> taskList = [SELECT Id, WhatId, CreatedDate FROM Task WHERE WhatId = :application.Id];
        System.assertEquals(true, taskList.isEmpty());

        try{
                application.Follow_Up_Date__c = System.today() + 2;
                update application;
            } catch(Exception e) {
            System.Assert(e.getMessage().contains('An activity must be logged today to change the Follow-Up Date'));
        } 

        applicationList = [SELECT Id, Follow_Up_Date__c, Last_Activity_Date__c FROM Application__c WHERE Id = :application.Id];
            System.assertEquals(null, applicationList[0].Last_Activity_Date__c);
            System.assertNotEquals(System.today(), applicationList[0].Follow_Up_Date__c);

        Task task = new Task(); 
            task.recordTypeId = '01236000000OkDPAA0';
            task.ActivityDate = System.today();
        task.WhatId = application.Id;
        task.Type = 'OutBound Phone Call';
            task.Subject = 'Call';
            task.Status = 'Completed';
            task.CreatedDate = System.now() -1;
            task.LastModifiedDate = System.now() -1;
            Task task2 = new Task(); 
            task2.recordTypeId = '01236000000OkDPAA0';
            task2.ActivityDate = System.today() + 2;
        task2.WhatId = application.Id;
        task2.Type = 'Email';
            task2.Subject = 'Email';
            task2.Status = 'Completed';
            task2.CreatedDate = System.now();
            task2.LastModifiedDate = System.now();
            insert new List<Task>{task, task2};

        taskList = [SELECT Id, WhatId, CreatedDate FROM Task WHERE WhatId = :application.Id];
        System.assertEquals(2, taskList.size());

        application.Follow_Up_Date__c = System.today();
        update application;

        applicationList = [SELECT Id, Follow_Up_Date__c, Last_Activity_Date__c FROM Application__c WHERE Id = :application.Id];
            System.assertEquals(System.today(), applicationList[0].Last_Activity_Date__c);
            System.assertEquals(System.today(), applicationList[0].Follow_Up_Date__c);
Test.stopTest();
        }
}
```

Trigger:

```
if (Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isInsert)){
        if (ApplicationHandler.firstRun){
            handler.firstApplicationRun();
            handler.updateLastActivityDate();
```

Comment: Hi @JayantDas I've updated my question to not be so broad. I think I've pinpointed my issue but I haven't been able to solve it on my own.

Comment: It seems that your `Utils.isFieldChanging()` is returning `false` and that's why no further lines are covered. You will need to ensure that this returns `true` for your other lines to be covered.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll check it out and let you know the outcome. Appreciate you taking a look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

> I've checked the debug logs and the application Id exists but the Id doesn't get populated in the Map. Any ideas on why the Map won't populate?

Your issue seems to be on the below line, where you are performing the check and only then your further code is executed.

```
if (Utils.isFieldChanging('Follow_Up_Date__c', application, Trigger.oldMap))
```

Without getting to know the details of how your method works, as of now based on your problem, it seems that your method is returning `false` with your test data and thus the execution will never get into the if block. And thus no subsequent lines will be covered. You will need to ensure that your test data is created in such a way that the logic is evaluated to be `true` it covers the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to get certain lines to execute in tests, sometimes it's best to start over. Write your tests first to ensure that the code does everything it's supposed to do, and then write your code until your tests all pass. 
If you're just writing for coverage, you're going at it wrong - and this is confirmed by this bit of code you can't get to execute. If you can't run it, why keep it in the first place? Or if you really think you need it but can't run it, step back and think about what your code should be doing, and start from that. 
This is a great indication that the code itself is the problem, not the test methods.